# can connect android device to ethernet and ping from adb shell but unable to browse internet

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I connected my android device(on a board) to internet through Ethernet cable but not able to browse anything on device.
Using adb shell, Ping to 8.8.8.8 is working but to www.google.com or other url is failing. Same through browser.
Can you please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
For Lollipop:

```
ndc resolver setnetdns eth0 "" 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

For Kitkat:

```
ndc resolver setifdns eth0 "" 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
ndc resolver setdefaultif eth0
```